# Static / Const Type *Const Difference

Tags: c

If I had a static constant char `'NAME'` as an array, by writing something such as the following:

```
static const *char NAME[8] = {"gregory"};
```

be the same as writing:

```
const char *const NAME[8] = {"gregory"};
```

By this I mean are they both static, I heard putting const again inside of the * makes it static.

I'm aware than static and constant/literal are different by having just `static char` or `const char`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The first line is ill-formed, maybe you meant `static const char *const NAME[8] = {"gregory"};`

Answer (score 1):

```
 `  static const  `
```

is over-specifying.  if you want a string which can't be altered use `const`.

If you are so inclined use  `#define NAME "gregory"`

Which works just as well.  Then you can have:

`strcat(*ptrOtherString,NAME);`

Comment: an array that is static and constant.
isn't it best to stay away from #DEFINE.

Comment: That's why I said 'if yore so inclined' I know some people don't like define for strings, and newer languages don't have it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `static` has three uses in C:

1. To make local variables lasting after exiting a block.
2. To make local variables lasting during the whole life-time of the program.
3. To prevent symbols from being exported to the linker, making them effectively "private" to the source file.

So in short, keyword `static` gives an object "static storage class", which gives it the above mentioned features.

> By this I mean are they both static, I heard putting const again inside of the * makes it static.

Not really. "static storage class" are given to objects by "storage class specifiers" such as `auto`, `register`, `static` and `extern`, not "type qualifiers" such as `const`. Obviously, one cannot do the job of the another one. Unless the second statement is outside a function, it's not "static", because of lack of keyword `static`.

Comment: Those two cases are basically saying the same thing.  Another use for `static` is to prevent symbols from being exported to the linker (making them effectively "private" to the source file).

Comment: @JohnBode Thanks, my answer is improved now.

Answer (score 1):

> By this I mean are they both static, I heard putting const again inside of the * makes it static.

That is not correct; `const` does not affect storage duration.  `static` storage duration means that the storage for the array is allocated at program startup and held until the program terminates.  `const` simply designates something as non-modifiable.

`const T *p` and `T const *p` both mean that `p` is a pointer to `const T`<sup>1</sup>; `p` is modifiable (you can set it to point to a different object), but `*p` is not (you cannot modify the thing `p` points to).

`T * const p` means that `p` is a *`const`* pointer to `T`; `*p` is modifiable (you can modify the thing `p` points to), but `p` is not (you cannot set `p` to point to a different thing).

`const T *const p` and `T const *const p` both mean that both `p` and `*p` are not modifiable.

To make something have `static` storage duration, you must either declare it at file scope (outside the body of any function) or with the `static` keyword.

---

<sup>1.  Type specifiers (`int`, `char`, `float`, etc.) and type qualifiers (`const`, `volatile`) may appear in any order in a declaration; `const unsigned long` and `long const unsigned` both mean the same thing, although your peers would probably beat you if you used the second form.  For now, this also applies to storage class specifiers (`static`, `auto`), although a future language revision may require that all storage class specifiers come first in a declaration</sup>